# how to get only those item which id is partyID

Tags: c#, linq

```
-----------------
partyId| ItemID |       
-----------------
 1     |    1   |
 1     |    2   |
 2     |    2   |
 2     |    3   |
 ----------------
```

```
-----------------
ItemID| Name    |       
-----------------
 1    | item1   |
 2    | item2   |
 3    | item3   |
 ----------------
```

how to get only those item which id is partyID

```
var partyId = 1;
 List<FinishedGoodsItem> itemList;
itemList = from i in _unitFinishedGoods.FGItem.GetAll().ToList()
           join p in _unitFinishedGoods.FGParty.GetAll(x => x.PartyId == partyId) on i.Id equals p.FGItemId
           select new FinishedGoodsItem() { 
                /// here how can I select only 'i' that means 1st table, which belongs to class FinishedGoodsItem()
                
           };
```

here table is demo table to understand. but code is from my project
here how can I select only 'i' that means 1st table, which belongs to class FinishedGoodsItem(). i can't selct only 1st table.

Comment: What is `_unitFinishedGoods`? What are `FGItem` and `FGParty`? What is `GetAll`? What is `FinishedGoodsItem`?

Comment: `_unitFinishedGoods.FGItem.GetAll().ToList()` from this full statement, i get only a list of  `FinishedGoodsItem` class

Comment: @Toha do you want all data from table 2 that belong to party id 1 ? ItemID| Name    |       
-----------------
 1    | item1   |
 2    | item2   |
 ---------------- ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear to me but since you don't give us important information about the table names or the structure of the `FinishedGoodsItem` class, I'll make some guesses. Is this what you're looking for?

```
var partyId = 1;    
List<FinishedGoodsItem> itemList = (from a in db.FGParty join b in db.FGItem 
                                        on a.ItemId equals b.ItemId
                                        where a.partyId == partyId
                                        select new FinishedGoodsItem
                                        {
                                           PartyID = partyId,
                                           ItemID = b.ItemID,
                                           Name = b.Name
                                        }).ToList();
```